# Get WMI Memory Values using Perl

Tags: perl, wmi

I need to collect memory data of Windows operating systems using WMI. In that sense, I developed a Perl script to generate such data. However, I wonder if my method is correct and what are the alternatives. It is intended that the method of collecting data is to be as widely as possible in terms of Windows OS's.

If you are not a perlish, this is what I what to check:

```
MEM_USED = Win32_OperatingSystem->TotalVisibleMemorySize - Win32_OperatingSystem->FreePhysicalMemory
SWAP_USED = (Win32_OperatingSystem->SizeStoredInPagingFiles - Win32_OperatingSystem->FreeSpaceInPagingFiles) /  Win32_OperatingSystem->SizeStoredInPagingFiles
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/env perl

use Win32::OLE;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $wmi = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
  or die "Failed getobject\n";

my $list, my $v;

$list = $wmi->InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
  or die "Failed getobject\n";

my $end_time = time;


my ($total_mem, $free_mem, $used_mem, $mem_percent, $free_percent);

foreach $v (in $list) {

  $total_mem = $v->{TotalVisibleMemorySize};
  $free_mem = $v->{FreePhysicalMemory};
  $used_mem = $total_mem - $free_mem;
  $mem_percent = sprintf("%.2f", $used_mem / $total_mem * 100);
  $free_percent  =  sprintf("%.2f", $free_mem / $total_mem * 100);

  print "Memory used: $mem_percent\%\n";
  print "Memory free: $free_percent\%\n";
  print "Memory total: $total_mem kb\n";
  print "Memory used: $used_mem kb\n";
  print "Memory free: $free_mem kb\n";

  my $total_swap_mem = $v->{SizeStoredInPagingFiles};
  my $free_swap_mem = $v->{FreeSpaceInPagingFiles};
  my $used_swap_mem = $total_swap_mem - $free_swap_mem;
  my $used_swap_mem_perc = ($total_swap_mem - $free_swap_mem) / $total_swap_mem * 100;

  printf "Swap total:%d kb\n", $total_swap_mem;
  printf "Swap free:%d kb\n", $free_swap_mem;
  printf "Swap used:%d kb\n", $used_swap_mem;
  printf "Swap used:%.2f %%\n", $used_swap_mem_perc;
}
```

**Note:** At 2011-01-19 I've updated this script, since at that time there were no conflicts with posted comments.

Comment: Looks good from here. `winmgmts` and `Win32_OperatingSystem` are supported since Windows 2000. Do you need to support anything older than that?

Comment: Hum... I think its wrong!!! After some google research I've found that:
Virtual Memory = PhysicalMemory(RAM) + Extended Memory (Disk)

I need to recreat the script...

Comment: I've have update the perl script... is it correct now?

Comment: gulden PT, what is the question exactly? -- Are you asking whether the WMI properties are being used correctly, or if the script is good perl?

Comment: The first, but if you would like to answer "if the script is good perl?", it will be also useful for me.

Comment: The Perl script is supposed to run only on Windows machine right?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to take a look at this little Perl project:

[Check WMI Plus](http://www.edcint.co.nz/checkwmiplus/)

It's client less, works under Linux and works also with remote Windows machines. I've been using it recently in order to monitor memory usage.