# Program in c or Perl to find out which port of USB is being used?

Tags: c, perl

Is there any way i can find out if a particular device is being plugged into a USB port and which USB port number is it plugged in, using C or Perl programming?

Comment: You must realize that this is, at least for C, highly platform-specific. Please specify the platform, at least.

Comment: The answer will be highly OS- and platform-specific. More info will be needed.

Comment: frankly have no answer to this one... all i can say is i shall be using the same for windows 7/vista. the problem i'm facing is that i have a medical device. every time i plug it in a usb port(different from the previous one) the port number changes... and hence i have to go and change the port options in my device software. So just if i have a exe which would gimme the port to which i have that device connected... would make my life simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There are portable means like using [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/doc/) to enumerate all devices.

Also, you can use OS specific features, like `devfs` or `lsusb` on Linux, or the registry or WMI on Windows.

The command `lsusb` shows you all connected devices. You can find the same information in the sysfs directory `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`.

On Windows you can dig through the registry at `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB`, or [use WMI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/02/24/displaying-usb-devices-using-wmi.aspx). WMI is accessible not only by Powershell, you can [use Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726968/get-wmi-memory-values-using-perl) as well.

But, the preferred way is to use `libusb` because of its portability.

Comment: @ daxim, @werewindle:  Thanks guys i shall start on this soon and keep u updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux you can just call ***lsusb*** from your script.